# Is there any way to pass user variables to a CA Workload Automation job?

Tags: workload-scheduler, workload

I have a JOB in CA Workload Automation that runs a shell script, this shell receives 4 parameters, two of these parameters are global variables but the other two must be given by a user when the JOB is run.

As an example, my shell must be run like this:

./Shell.sh par1 par2 par3 par4

par2 and par3 are goblal variables and set as such, but I need the user to input par1 and par4.

I've looked everywhere but it seems like CAWA just doesn't work like this,

Any help is much appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately Autosys WA does not provide this kind of functionality.